# smarty assign column name variables and values for single record

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am very new to Smarty so take it easy on me, I saw one guy say refer to the FAQ, however, I cannot find this in the FAQ link or anywhere else that I have spent a few hours searching, thanks:

I see many many posts referring to how to iterate through a bunch of rows returned from a mysql query. I want to know if there is a way to assign the variables and names without typing them all out on the PHP side before displaying the smarty template. Example:

```
mysql query returns a single row of data which has columns username, fname, lname (and a bunch of others): 
$qry="SELECT * FROM people WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
```

so if I don't assign each one individually, like this:

```
$peoples = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$username=$peoples['username'];
$fname=$peoples['fname'];
$lname=$peoples['lname'];
```

...and so forth, and then:

```
$smarty->assign('username', $username);
$smarty->assign('fname', $fname);
$smarty->assign('lname', $lname);
```

...and so forth, and then:

```
$smarty->display('templates/person.tpl');
```

and use the {$username} {$fname} {$lname} and so forth
in the template. Is there some way to iterate through the associated array from the mysql_fetch_assoc and assign those variables and smarty variables automatically?

I saw something like:

```
   while($row   = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $this->append("peoples", $row);
      $rows[] = $row;
   }
```

But it doesn't seem to do what I am asking and I don't really understand how to get to what I need, please help, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use the `mysql_*` functions anymore. They're deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Look it up on php.net

Comment: Um thanks Rudie, will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the first row:

```
// php
$person = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$smarty->assign('person', $person);

// tpl
{{$person.fname}}
```

If you want all the people:

```
// php
$people = array();
while ( $person = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  $people[] = $person;
}
$smarty->assign('people', $people);

// tpl
{{foreach from=$people item=person}}
  - {{person.fname}}
{{/foreach}}
```

Comment: yes! that works, thanks! Is this typically how this sort of thing is done where you are searching for a single record and need to display and/or edit it?

Comment: I don't think there is a 'typical' in software development =) especially PHP, but this is a simple way of finding and passing records. When you're more experienced and make bigger apps, you'll want to look into [Models](http://www.slideshare.net/brandonsavage/beautiful-models-in-php), so you can do stuff like: `$people = Person::all('foo = bar');` and then every $person is a `Person` object. Maybe later!

Comment: Yeah, thanks again Rudie. As for Models, I am not a real programmer, perhaps one day I will delve in over there! I kind of understand objects and inheritance though, best regards!

Comment: ps I would like to bump your reply as useful, however, I have not enough reputation on here to do that, sorry!

Comment: I don't see anywhere where it let's me "accept" it.

Comment: Thanks, doh, it's intuitively obvious! ;)